Windows 11 RDP connection to Windows Server 2022 - credSSP error
From fully patched Windows 11 client, connecting to a fully patched Windows Server 2022 returns this error: credSSP error
I tried  setting HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system\CredSSP\Parameters!AllowEncryptionOracle to 2, trying the same via group policy etc.
Client and server are joined to the same domain and separated by SD-WAN, communication isn't firewalled.
Wireshark trace on the client reveals a reply from the server stating:
"failureCode: Server requires Enhanced RDP Security with CredSSP (0x00000005)"
Any proposal is appreciated.
Addendum:
I have tried to compare Wireshark traces from healthy and unhealthy client. Last two bytes for target server are: 101.16. The unhealthy client's last two bytes are: 1.8 and last two bytes for healthy client are:105.201. I am attaching two screenshots - 1st screenshot shows the healthy client (light UI of Wireshark) on the left and first negotiate request of un-healthy client (dark UI of Wireshark) on the right. Second screenshots shows second attempt of unhealthy client to re-negotiate the connection.
Healthy (left) and unhealthy(right) clients comparison
2nd negotiation attempt of unhealthy client
Please note that 2nd negotiation attempt of unhealthy client contains CredSSP bit = 0. Why is that so is beyond my understanding.
Addendum 2
OK, after a bit more of testing, I got following result (on different target server as the server 101.16 isn't domain joined):

Connecting to a domain-joined server (FQDN) with domain account - OK
Connecting to a domain-joined server (IP addr.) with local account - NOT OK
Connecting to a domain joined server (FQDN) with local account - NOT OK

NOT OK meaning I am always getting the CredSSP error.

It seems to be a mismatch; have you set AllowEncryptionOracle to both machines? Since they are both current and fully patched, you can set the highest level to both. So RDP will be possible and secured.

It returns the same error if AllowEncryptionOracle =0 on both client and server, dtto. for AllowEncryptionOracle = 2. The only way I can RDP to server from client is, when I uncheck "NLA" in RDP settings of the server. From a different laptop in the same domain, the RDP works flawlessly.

AllowEncryptionOracle is for older Windows systems. You didn't specify details of the systems that you are using NLA to authenticate against.

I am trying to remote to Win2022 21H2. I am trying to remote from client with Win11 23H2.

That is information about the source and destination hosts. That doesn't provide information about the host providing authentication for NLA.

If I get your question right, then: The credentials I am using is the local user on the server (the target of my RDP connection). The server isn't domain joined, my client is. The behavior is consistent regardless of whether I am trying to connect to domain-joined server or not.
